# Откуда пустые строчки или переносы в цикле?

Tags: php, pdo

Когда достаю результат через *Ajax* выходит, что в цикле есть 5 пустых строк 
и только потом выводится `echo`:

```html
<?php
// including the config file
include('config.php');
$pdo = connect();


$last_id = $_POST['last_id'];



$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE id > :last_id LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindParam(':last_id', $last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

while ($rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<h2>'.$rs['title'].'</h2>';
  echo '<img src="'.$rs['photo'].'">';
  echo '<p>'.$rs['description'].'</p>';
  echo '</li>';
}


?>
```

Comment: config.php просмотрите.

Comment: Что пытались сделать для отладки?

Comment: А зачем нужен цикл, если из БД читается заведомо только 1 запись. И что такое "пустые строки", кстати, просто переводы кареток или набор пустых тегов

Comment: Согласен с Mike, зачем цикл, если у вас Limit 1 тоесть одна строка?

Comment: Лимит, тут просто для примера, я планирую 10 записей выводить, но пока не знаю, что делать  если в бд не 10 записей, а меньше после последнего id. вот last_id += 1;

Comment: А если без цикла, то как должно быть правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Надо проверить наличие пустых строк

**до** `<?php`

и

**после** `?>`

При обнаружении пустых строк - удалить.

2) Сделать тоже самое в config.php

**UPD** Из документации

> Если файл содержит только код PHP, предпочтительно опустить
>   закрывающий тег в конце файла. Это помогает избежать добавления
>   случайных символов пробела или перевода строки после закрывающего тега
>   PHP, которые могут послужить причиной нежелательных эффектов, так как
>   PHP начинает выводить данные в буфер при отсутствии намерения у
>   программиста выводить какие-либо данные в этой точке скрипта.

Comment: `есть 5 пустых строк и ТОЛЬКО ПОТОМ выводится echo`.

Comment: В config.php были строчки спасибо большое